# Removing whitespace in XElement closing tag

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

I have some XML that I am building that looks like this:

```
<actionitem actiontaken="none" target="0" targetvariable="0">
  <windowname>Popup Window</windowname>
  <windowposx>-1</windowposx>
  <windowposy>-1</windowposy>
  <windowwidth>-1</windowwidth>
  <windowheight>-1</windowheight>
  <noscrollbars>false</noscrollbars>
  <nomenubar />
  <notoolbar />
  <noresize />
  <nostatus />
  <nolocation />
  <browserWnd />
</actionitem>
```

This XML has to be to the exact specifications of the client, meaning I can't have a whitespace in the closing tag.  I know that MSDN says this:

> When writing an empty element, an additional space is added between tag name and 
>   the closing tag, for example . This provides compatibility with older browsers.

But, the client won't/can't budge on this.  So, I thought I could try something like this to remedy the problem:

```
xelement.ReplaceWith(" />", "/>");
```

But when I run the program, I get this error message:

```
Non white space characters cannot be added to content.
```

[image: Error message]

So, does anyone know how I can remove that white space once I've built the XML document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do it using an `XElement`, the best option will be to read the `Xml` as text but to avoid unnecessary excess string allocation, do it via a string builder:

```
var element = new XElement...;

var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter(stringBuilder))
{
    element.Save(stringWriter);
}

stringBuilder.Replace(" />", "/>");
var xml = stringBuilder.ToString();

Console.WriteLine(xml);
```

Any method which does a `.ToString().Replace()` is going to be far more costly in terms of memory usage.

The worrying thing about your client's comment is that it sounds like they have a home made xml parser which isn't very good, the whitespace in a self closing tag should not make a difference.

Comment: Yes, as far as the client (Department of Defense) is concerned, they've "been doing it this way for a long time" and it would take an act of Congress to get them to change it.

Comment: I like this, because I can scan through the document while in memory.  Let me try this out and see how it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I would read `XML` content as text then `Replace` the spaces like this:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("path");
for(int i=0;i<lines.Length;i++)
{
   if (lines[i].Contains(" />")) lines[i] = lines[i].Replace(" />", "/>");
}
File.WriteAllLines("path", lines);
```

Comment: I may try to modify this so that I can loop through the document while it's in memory and not already saved in a file.  I'll try that now.